# Trouble assigning listener to class

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, nullpointerexception, listener

My problem consists in inexplicable inability listen to one of my classes.

The software is a **java swing-based desktop** application, where the JFrame's child class called MainFrame is listening to multiple **dialogs**. All the dialog windows are children of my PDialog class, which carries the listener-related variables and functions. This is what PDialog class looks like:

```
public class PDialog extends JDialog {

private MainFrameChildrenListener listener;

// Function that assigns its parameter to local listener value "listener setter"
public void addMainFrameChildrenListener(MainFrameChildrenListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public void removeMainFrameChildrenListener() {
    this.listener = null;
}

public void firePDialogEvent(MainFrameChildrenEventObject event) {
    this.listener.dialogEventOccured(event);
}

// This method was useful when I tried to debug with System.out.println() method
public String retrieveListenerInformation(){
    if(listener == null){
        return "No listener loaded";
    }
    return this.listener.toString();
}
}
```

So I have created 3 dialogs that I listen to successfully using functions they inherited as PDialog's children classes. The MainFrame class implements MainFrameChildrenListener listener object and it is passed as listener to the dialogs in its constructor:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements MainFrameChildrenListener {

private PDialogCustomer dialogCustomer = new PDialogCustomer();
private PDialogOrder dialogOrder = new PDialogOrder();
private PDialogProduct dialogProduct = new PDialogProduct();
private PDialogMaterial dialogMaterial = new PDialogMaterial();

public MainFrame(){
    dialogMaterial.addMainFrameChildrenListener(this);
    dialogCustomer.addMainFrameChildrenListener(this);
    dialogOrder.addMainFrameChildrenListener(this);
    dialogProduct.addMainFrameChildrenListener(this);


    System.out.println("Material dialog: " + dialogMaterial.retrieveListenerInformation());
    System.out.println("Customer dialog: " + dialogCustomer.retrieveListenerInformation());
    System.out.println("Order dialog: " + dialogOrder.retrieveListenerInformation());
    System.out.println("Product dialog: " + dialogProduct.retrieveListenerInformation());
}
```

Surprisingly after the launch of the application the console outputs the PDialog.retrieveListenerInformation() instruction and this is what it looks like:

```
Material dialog: No listener loaded
Customer dialog: view.MainFrame[-deleted the .toString() rubbish to keep things short-]
Order dialog: view.MainFrame[-deleted the .toString() rubbish to keep things short-]
Product dialog: view.MainFrame[-deleted the .toString() rubbish to keep things short-]
```

And if I try to *fire* the listener event I get **null pointer exception** for the PDialog.firePDialogEvent() method.
I have tried to pass the listener to the PDialogMaterial class through its constructor, I even tried to create new method only within PDialogMaterial class to pass the listener and with no luck. The only way I was able to make things work was create new MainFrameChildrenListener variable which was declared **public** (eek!) and accessed it **directly** (eeeeek!) from MainFrame constructor like so:

```
public class PDialogMaterial extends PDialog{
public MainFrameChildrenListener testListener;
}

public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements MainFrameChildrenListener{
  public MainFrame(){
    dialogMaterial.testListener = this;
    dialogCustomer.addMainFrameChildrenListener(this);
    dialogOrder.addMainFrameChildrenListener(this);
    dialogProduct.addMainFrameChildrenListener(this);

  }
}
```

Is there any explanation as to why 3 out of 4 classes that all inherited **identical** listener-handling methods behave differently than the fourth class? What could I be missing?

Comment followup:

The complete code for PDialogMaterial (not working):

```
package view.dialogs;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import view.listeners.MainFrameChildrenEventObject;
import view.listeners.MainFrameChildrenListener;
import view.utils.DoubleFormatCheck;

public class PDialogMaterial extends PDialog {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6190469565649183032L;

    // private PMaterialFabricObject fabricObject;

    public static final int FABRIC_MASK = 0;
    public static final int STRAP_MASK = 1;
    public static final int PARTS_MASK = 2;
    public static final int THREAD_MASK = 3;

    private String[] fabricMaterialList = { "Cotton", "Brocate", "Satin", "Synthetic" };
    private String[] fabricColorsList = { "Red", "Green", "Blue", "Purple", "Gray", "Yellow", "Black", "Khakhi",
            "Carcaline" };

    private MainFrameChildrenListener listener;

    private GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    private Dimension size = new Dimension(300, 300);

    private DoubleFormatCheck dfc = new DoubleFormatCheck();

    private JTextField nameField = new JTextField(8);
    private JTextField priceField = new JTextField(6);
    private JTextField widthField = new JTextField(6);
    private JTextField vendorField = new JTextField(8);

    private JButton okButton = new JButton("Ok");
    private JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");

    private DefaultComboBoxModel<String> fabricMaterialComboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(
            fabricMaterialList);
    private DefaultComboBoxModel<String> materialColorComboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(
            fabricColorsList);
    private JComboBox<String> fabricMaterialComboBox = new JComboBox<String>(fabricMaterialComboBoxModel);
    private JComboBox<String> fabricColorComboBox = new JComboBox<String>(materialColorComboBoxModel);

    public PDialogMaterial(){

    }

    public void addMainFrameChildrenListener(MainFrameChildrenListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void removeMainFrameChildrenListener() {
        this.listener = null;
    }

    public void firePDialogMaterialEventOccured(MainFrameChildrenEventObject event) {
        this.listener.dialogEventOccured(event);
    }

    public ImageIcon getPicture(String path) {
        URL link = this.getClass().getResource(path);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(link);
        return icon;
    }

    public void setFabricMask() {

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gc.gridheight = 1;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

        // First line - picture
        gc.gridwidth = 2;

        this.add(new JLabel(getPicture("/images/material_32pos.gif")), gc);

        gc.gridwidth = 1;

        // Second line - name
        gc.gridy++;
        this.add(new JLabel("Name: "), gc);

        gc.gridx++;
        this.add(nameField, gc);

        // Third line - material
        gc.gridx--;
        gc.gridy++;
        this.add(new JLabel("Material: "), gc);

        gc.gridx++;
        this.add(fabricMaterialComboBox, gc);

//      Fourth line - vendor name
        gc.gridx--;
        gc.gridy++;
        this.add(new JLabel("Vendor: "), gc);

        gc.gridx++;
        this.add(vendorField, gc);

        // Fifth line - predominating color
        gc.gridx--;
        gc.gridy++;
        this.add(new JLabel("Predominaing color: "), gc);

        gc.gridx++;
        this.add(fabricColorComboBox, gc);

        // Sixth line - price
        gc.gridx--;
        gc.gridy++;
        this.add(new JLabel("Price per square meter: "), gc);

        gc.gridx++;
        this.add(priceField, gc);

        // Seventh line - control buttons
        gc.gridx--;
        gc.gridy++;
        this.add(okButton, gc);

        gc.gridx++;
        this.add(cancelButton, gc);
    }

    public void setStrapMask() {
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gc.gridheight = 1;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

        // First line - picture
        gc.gridwidth = 2;

        this.add(new JLabel(getPicture("/images/material_32pos.gif")), gc);

        gc.gridwidth = 1;

        // Second line - name
        gc.gridy++;
        this.add(new JLabel("Name: "), gc);

        gc.gridx++;
        this.add(nameField, gc);

        // Third line - strap width
        gc.gridx--;
        gc.gridy++;
        this.add(new JLabel("Width: "), gc);

        gc.gridx++;
        this.add(widthField, gc);

        // Fourth line - predominating color
        gc.gridx--;
        gc.gridy++;
        this.add(new JLabel("Predominaing color: "), gc);

        gc.gridx++;
        this.add(fabricColorComboBox, gc);

        // Fifth line - strap price
        gc.gridx--;
        gc.gridy++;
        this.add(new JLabel("Price per meter: "), gc);

        gc.gridx++;
        this.add(priceField, gc);

        // Sixth line - control buttons
        gc.gridx--;
        gc.gridy++;
        this.add(okButton, gc);

        gc.gridx++;
        this.add(cancelButton, gc);
    }

    public void constructPDialogMaterial(int maskType){
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(this.getParent());
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(PDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(size);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(false);
        this.setIconImage(getPicture("/images/material_32pos.gif").getImage());
        this.nameField.setBackground(this.getBackground());
        this.vendorField.setBackground(this.getBackground());
        this.priceField.setBackground(this.getBackground());

        switch (maskType) {

        case PDialogMaterial.FABRIC_MASK:
            this.setTitle("Fabric material");
            setFabricMask();
            break;

        case PDialogMaterial.STRAP_MASK:
            this.setTitle("Straps");
            setStrapMask();
            break;

        // TODO
        default:
            System.out.println("Oh noes! Something happend!");
        }

        okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                String priceString = dfc.removeWhitespacesAndSwapCommas(priceField.getText());

                if(dfc.testDoubleFormat(priceString)){

                    Double price = Double.valueOf(priceString);

                    MainFrameChildrenEventObject eventObject = new MainFrameChildrenEventObject(okButton, vendorField.getText(), nameField.getText(),
                            (String)materialColorComboBoxModel.getSelectedItem(), (String)materialColorComboBoxModel.getSelectedItem(),
                            price, PDialog.MATERIAL_EVENT_FABRIC);

                    firePDialogEvent(eventObject);

                    dispose();
                }

                else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(PDialogMaterial.this, "Wrong price format", "Format error",
                            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });

        cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The complete code for PDialogCustomer (working example):

```
      package view.dialogs;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import view.listeners.MainFrameChildrenEventObject;

public class PDialogCustomer extends PDialog {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8431597688560531951L;

    private GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    private URL imageLink;
    private URL iconLink;

    // New customer GUI setup
    JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Customer name: ");
    JLabel addressLabel = new JLabel("Customer address: ");
    JLabel dogLabel = new JLabel("Dog name: ");
    JTextField nameField = new JTextField(8);
    JTextField streetField = new JTextField(8);
    JTextField cityField = new JTextField(8);
    JTextField countryField = new JTextField(8);
    JTextField dogField = new JTextField(8);
    JButton okBttn = new JButton("Ok");
    JButton cancelBttn = new JButton("Cancel");

    // ________________________________________________________

    public PDialogCustomer() {

        String imagePath = "/images/customer_32pos.gif";
        String iconPath = "/images/customer_16pos.gif";

        this.iconLink = getClass().getResource(iconPath);
        this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(iconLink).getImage());
        this.imageLink = getClass().getResource(imagePath);
        this.setTitle("New customer");

        nameField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        nameField.setBackground(this.getBackground());
        streetField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Street"));
        streetField.setBackground(this.getBackground());
        cityField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("City"));
        cityField.setBackground(this.getBackground());
        countryField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Country"));
        countryField.setBackground(this.getBackground());
        dogField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Dogs name"));
        dogField.setBackground(this.getBackground());

        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        gc.gridheight = 1;
        gc.gridwidth = 2;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

        add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imageLink)));

        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gc.gridy++;
        add(nameLabel, gc);

        gc.gridx++;
        add(nameField, gc);

        gc.gridy++;
        gc.gridx--;
        add(addressLabel, gc);

        gc.gridx++;
        add(streetField, gc);

        gc.gridy++;
        add(cityField, gc);

        gc.gridy++;
        add(countryField, gc);

        gc.gridy++;
        gc.gridx--;
        add(dogLabel, gc);

        gc.gridx++;
        add(dogField, gc);

        gc.gridy++;
        gc.gridx--;
        add(okBttn, gc);

        gc.gridx++;
        add(cancelBttn, gc);

        okBttn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String address = streetField.getText() + ", " + cityField.getText() + ", " + countryField.getText();
                firePDialogEvent(new MainFrameChildrenEventObject(okBttn, nameField.getText(), address,
                        dogField.getText(), PDialog.CUSTOMER_EVENT));
                dispose();
            }
        });

        cancelBttn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Comment: Post the code for `PDialogMaterial` and one of the others like  `PDialogOrder`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have followed the stack trace and found the method that threw the null pointer. It did not bring me closer to the solution because other classes use this method without any problems.  And after scratch recreation with simplified classes I did not get the exception again. I am working on Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example but it might take a while :( do you need the model and controller part?

Comment: *"..do you need the model and controller part?"* We need the MC that is a VE. Read the links & ask about anything you don't understand. I am well placed to explain, given I'm the author of the SSCCE, as well as the initial draft of the MCVE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/230513)

Answer (score 2):

The problem in the offending class is that it redeclares a

```
private MainFrameChildrenListener listener;
```

field. So you have two private fields, one in the superclass, and one in the subclass, with the same name. The one in the subclass overrides the one in the superclass when you are in methods of that subclass, but is not visible for methods defined in the superclass. Remove the listener field in the subclass, and it should work.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you for your effort and the time you took to go through my spaghetti software! It worked and now I can finally continue.

Answer (score 1):

As [Markus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39316313/6748496) already said, in your not-working listener you are hiding the listener-field and redeclare the setter.

To illustrate this problem, I built up a small example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HiddenField {

    static abstract class Base {
        String field = "BASE";

        // sets the base's field
        void setField(String set) {
            this.field = set;
        }

        // ensures not to be overridden and returns the base's field.
        final String getField() {
            return this.field;
        }

        // access the field by getter (ensured to be base) and field 'field'
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": get()->" + getField() + " vs. field->" + field;
        }
    }

    static class ProperExtension extends Base {
        /* no need to override the base's field */
    }

    static class HidingExtension extends Base {

        // this field isn't related to the one in Base, but has the same name!
        String field = "HIDING";

        // the setter is overridden (exact copy!) but because of the same-named
        // field in this extending class, it sets this class's field and not the
        // one in the base-class!
        @Override
        void setField(String set) {
            this.field = set;
        }

        // copied the toString from above - here it is accessing the
        // base-class's field via getter and this class's field directly.
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": get()->" + getField() + " vs. field->" + field;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // build both types of extending classes and invoke their setters
        Arrays.asList(new ProperExtension(), new HidingExtension()).forEach(obj -> {
            System.out.println("before ~> " + obj);
            obj.setField("SET");
            System.out.println("after  ~> " + obj + "\n");
        });
    }
}
```